# can't really understand the math behind the mandelbrot set

Tags: fractals, mandelbrot

according the following article : [wolfram Mandelbrot set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html), I'm trying to understand how they exactly managed to calculate the `Ln(C)=Zn=R(max) values.` 
i do understand that Rmax is a constant, equals 2,(|Zn| < 4 for all points that are inside the Mandelbrot set), and Ln(C) should be the amount of iterations i spent for each C(point), but how using these 2 i get to calculate

```
L1(C)   =   C   
L2(C)   =   C(C+1)
          ....
          ....
```

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start by setting z=C (or, basically equivalently as it happens, z=0) and then repeatedly setting z := z^2+C. Keep doing this until you get a z with |z|>Rmax.

If you never do -- of course in practice you won't go on literally for ever, but will stop after a certain maximum number of iterations -- then your point is in the Mandelbrot set, and if you're drawing a picture you typically colour it black.

If after N iterations you *do* get |z|>Rmax, then your point wasn't in the Mandelbrot set, and N gives some indication of how thoroughly outside the set it is; if you're drawing a picture, you typically plot the point in a colour determined by N.

The description of L_n on the Wolfram page is pretty bad. What they mean is: define L_n(C) to be the value of z after n iterations when you use the parameter C; then you can plot the curves defined by |L_n(c)|=Rmax. These are the boundaries between the different-coloured regions when you plot points as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the great comment, regarding your last paragraph, so can you give me a short example how to calculate the first L3/L4 values?
i understand the theory behind it.. but simply can't understand how to use that function recursively. there is no building rule on how to use L2 when you already have L1 value(C). Thanks alot!

Comment: (I'm not sure whether I've correctly understood your question, so please let me know if the following doesn't address it.) The first few z values you get in the iteration are: C, C^2+C, (C^2+C)^2+C, ((C^2+C)^2+C)^2+C, etc. (Each one equals the previous one squared + C.) So those are L1, L2, L3, L4, etc.